# Satellite image segmentation using transfer learning with input image of different size and channels

Tags: raster, sentinel-2, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new to Deep Learning and recently developed land cover products using U-Net architecture. I have been using an open-source library called [segmentation_model](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models) and it worked pretty well with a mean IoU of .72 for the RGB input rasters. I have used the resnet34 backbone and weights from imagenet to achieve this score.

However, now I would like to add a few more bands like nir,swir etc. to my sentinel 2 input rasters to further improve the accuracy. After careful consideration and reading a few blogs, I decided to use transfer learning for a 5 channels input raster.

Changing image height and width doesn't affect the number of parameters in the model. However, increasing the number of channels will increase the number of parameters.

I am again using the segmentation_model library with the resnet34 backbone and imagenet weights. Let me attach the partial summary of the original model:

---

```
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 data (InputLayer)              [(None, None, None,  0           []                               
                                 3)]                                                              
                                                                                                  
 bn_data (BatchNormalization)   (None, None, None,   9           ['data[0][0]']                   
                                3)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_34 (ZeroPadding  (None, None, None,   0          ['bn_data[0][0]']                
 2D)                            3)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv0 (Conv2D)                 (None, None, None,   9408        ['zero_padding2d_34[0][0]']      
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 bn0 (BatchNormalization)       (None, None, None,   256         ['conv0[0][0]']                  
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 relu0 (Activation)             (None, None, None,   0           ['bn0[0][0]']                    
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_35 (ZeroPadding  (None, None, None,   0          ['relu0[0][0]']                  
 2D)                            64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 pooling0 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, None, None,   0           ['zero_padding2d_35[0][0]']      
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, None, None,   256        ['pooling0[0][0]']               
 zation)                        64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_relu1 (Activation  (None, None, None,   0          ['stage1_unit1_bn1[0][0]']       
 )                              64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_36 (ZeroPadding  (None, None, None,   0          ['stage1_unit1_relu1[0][0]']     
 2D)                            64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, None, None,   36864       ['zero_padding2d_36[0][0]']      
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, None, None,   256        ['stage1_unit1_conv1[0][0]']     
 zation)                        64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_relu2 (Activation  (None, None, None,   0          ['stage1_unit1_bn2[0][0]']       
 )                              64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_37 (ZeroPadding  (None, None, None,   0          ['stage1_unit1_relu2[0][0]']     
 2D)                            64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 ...                                                                
 final_conv (Conv2D)            (None, None, None,   1160        ['decoder_stage4b_relu[0][0]']   
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 softmax (Activation)           (None, None, None,   0           ['final_conv[0][0]']             
                                8)                                                                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,457,169
Trainable params: 24,439,819
Non-trainable params: 17,350
```

Now I used the configuration dictionary from the original model and updated the image shape with my desired number of channels and loaded a new model from this config. Partial summary of the updated model attached here

```
Model: "model_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 data (InputLayer)              [(None, 256, 256, 5  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 bn_data (BatchNormalization)   (None, 256, 256, 5)  15          ['data[0][0]']                   
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_34 (ZeroPadding  (None, 262, 262, 5)  0          ['bn_data[0][0]']                
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv0 (Conv2D)                 (None, 128, 128, 64  15680       ['zero_padding2d_34[0][0]']      
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 bn0 (BatchNormalization)       (None, 128, 128, 64  256         ['conv0[0][0]']                  
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 relu0 (Activation)             (None, 128, 128, 64  0           ['bn0[0][0]']                    
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_35 (ZeroPadding  (None, 130, 130, 64  0          ['relu0[0][0]']                  
 2D)                            )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 pooling0 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           ['zero_padding2d_35[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 64, 64, 64)  256         ['pooling0[0][0]']               
 zation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_relu1 (Activation  (None, 64, 64, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit1_bn1[0][0]']       
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_36 (ZeroPadding  (None, 66, 66, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit1_relu1[0][0]']     
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 64, 64, 64)   36864       ['zero_padding2d_36[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 64, 64, 64)  256         ['stage1_unit1_conv1[0][0]']     
 zation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 stage1_unit1_relu2 (Activation  (None, 64, 64, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit1_bn2[0][0]']       
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 zero_padding2d_37 (ZeroPadding  (None, 66, 66, 64)  0           ['stage1_unit1_relu2[0][0]']     
 2D)                                                                                              
 ...                            )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 final_conv (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 8)  1160        ['decoder_stage4b_relu[0][0]']   
                                                                                                  
 softmax (Activation)           (None, 256, 256, 8)  0           ['final_conv[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,463,447
Trainable params: 24,446,093
Non-trainable params: 17,354
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

From the summary above I can confirm that only the number of parameters from the bn_data (BatchNormalization) and conv0 layers have changed. Hence, I expand the weight dimensions to more accurately represent the increase in channels and copy over the mean of the weights for both layers. This didn't help much, I have run over 1000 epochs but my mean IoU is still .0388. FYI, I have over 500 training data sets and 144 validation datasets.